# Article or no article?

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why not use the article?

> The starting point of all achievements is ***the/a*** desire

Comment: to ... the sentence is unfinished. A complete sentence would be "The starting point of all achievements is desire."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Desire” is an abstract idea, and this sentence is about that general concept- as opposed to “a desire” or “the desire”, which are more concrete and specific- for example, “a desire to learn English”, “the deepest desire” might be when you would use “a” or “the”.